# Непонятные исключения при запуске приложения

Tags: java, android

При запуске приложения вылетает вот такое вот исключение. Это появилось при попытке добавления push-уведомлений в приложение. Создал другой проект, добавил все то же самое (для push-уведомлений) и никаких исключений не вылетело. Хотелось бы хоть примерно понять, в чем причина.
Лог:

```
08-21 01:05:29.760 14421-14421/com.example.uncolor.aroundme E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.uncolor.aroundme, PID: 14421
                                                                              java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzb(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzac; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac' appears in /data/app/com.example.uncolor.aroundme-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes13.dex)
                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition$Builder.build(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.onInflate(Fragment.java:1296)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3672)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:183)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:731)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:812)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:510)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:420)
                                                                                  at com.example.uncolor.aroundme.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:88)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2343)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:799)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2199)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:651)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:145)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1236)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1084)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1614)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18026)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:963)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18026)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5702)
                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18026)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5702)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:393)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18026)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5702)
                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18026)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5702)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1692)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:760)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18026)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5702)
                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWind
08-21 01:05:29.848 958-1080/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '30f2d372 com.example.uncolor.aroundme/com.example.uncolor.aroundme.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавь в `build.gradle`

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:+"
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+'
```